# How to use ConfigSlurper to configure a JavaBean

Tags: groovy, configuration, config, configuration-files, configure

The JavaDoc of [`ConfigSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigSlurper.html) says

> Settings can either be bound into nested maps or onto a specified JavaBean instance.

How does the latter work?
I only find examples of using the result as map or properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two beans:

```
@groovy.transform.ToString
class Child {
    Integer age
}

@groovy.transform.ToString
class Bean {
    String name
    Child child
}
```

We can parse some config into a `Bean`:

```
Bean b = new ConfigSlurper().parse('''
   name = 'tim'
   child {
       age = 5
   }
''')
```

Then printing `b` gives:

```
 Bean(tim, Child(5))
```

Comment: Ah, so a simple cast will create the corresponding beans out of the `ConfigObject`? Very interesting, thanks. One more question though, is it also possible to configure an existing object with the parse result? e. g. if you already have an instance of `Bean` that has some more properties and just set the properties defined in the config script into the existing instance?

Comment: do you have any idea?